# How can I replace patio cover columns?

Tags: repair, wood, waterproofing

My patio cover has wood columns (that support the over hang) that actually go into the ground and are rotten.   I really need to fix this but not sure how to go about it.   It has 4 columns.   I'm assuming they need to be on concrete and the wood out of the ground.   Please help.

Comment: Some use a can-do attitude, a pile of chocking material and an apparent disregard for personal safety :-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_0vRaDJXn4

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Dude's lucky the come-along didn't rip out the cabin support.

Comment: Picture would help.

Comment: Fiberglass columns have solved this problem for many. They might be worth a look from you.

Answer (score 1):

Under no circumstances wooden columns should be placed on the ground. Connection between ground and column should be small metal element like this:

[image]
It would be best if you could make small concrete foundation which would be connected with this metal element with some anchor bolts